# Apply animation while loading multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions, riot.js

I want to apply animation using either css or JQuery while loading divs.

The divs get loaded this way:

```
<div>
    <blog_topic_title each="{item , i in data.blogTopicsArr}" index={i} id={item.article_id} topic={item}></blog_topic_title>
</div>
```

Data:

```
this.data.blogTopicsArr = [1,2,3];
```

On page load, we see that there are 3 items in the array, so three `tags` are created like this:

```
<blog_topic_title>{opts.topic}</<blog_topic_title>
<blog_topic_title>{opts.topic}</<blog_topic_title>
<blog_topic_title>{opts.topic}</<blog_topic_title>
```

While the above three divs are created inside the loop, I want to pass in some animation using css or JQuery while looping so it looks like this:
 https://codepen.io/elmahdim/pen/sGkvH or may be some thing similar.

I tried applying css animation using transitions, but unable to get effect like in the link.

Answer (score -1):

```
You can use **[wow.js][1]** for this purpose.

  [1]: http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/

<blog_topic_title  class="wow slideInLeft" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay="5s">{opts.topic}</<blog_topic_title>
<blog_topic_title  class="wow slideInRight" data-wow-offset="10"  data-wow-iteration="10">{opts.topic}</<blog_topic_title>
<blog_topic_title class="wow bounceInUp">{opts.topic}</<blog_topic_title>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! While answers are always appreciated, please [**don't just link libraries**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605/2341603). The library will **probably** become outdated, and the link to the page could break in the future, which might [**detract from your answer**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259). In fact, answers that are little more than a link [**may be deleted**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers). A few sentences covering the key points about *how* your library helps would really go a long way!

Comment: ... especially since this isn't freeware!